# sort .txt file by highest score not working

Tags: c#

in class i have a task to make a game, and i have to make a leaderboard/high score list using a .txt file and .txt file only.

my file is like this

```
name 1, 6
name 2, 3
name 3, 9
```

And what I want it to look like

```
name 3, 9
name 1, 6
name 2, 3
```

I can display the text file. I'm using a listbox, but I can't sort it before displaying.

here is the code snippet

```
 private void Leaderboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] scores = File.ReadAllLines(filepath); //filepath is equal to @database.txt file
        var orderedScores = scores.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1]));
        foreach (var entry in orderedScores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scores);
        }

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"database.txt");
        while (line != null)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                scoreboard.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

I have tried modifying the code and used different symbols to split the words (; ? $) instead of , but it hasnt worked. There are no errors when running, it just doesnt sort the file. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why do you read the same file twice?  This method looks like it's performing two different operations, one attempts to sort the values and output them to the console, the other tries to add them to whatever `scoreboard` is (without sorting the records).  Which operation are you asking about?

Comment: try  var orderedScores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[2]))

Comment: Trim the String that you are parsing: int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1].Trim())

Comment: Is this a typo _"Console.WriteLine(scores);"_ printing out the unordered array of strings each iteration - it should be _"Console.WriteLine(entry);"_

Comment: @David I am asking about the attempt to sort the values. I want it to sort the text file and re write it once sorted. the other just adds the txt it to the listbox scoreboard to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually sorting the file.

```
var orderedScores = scores.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1]));
```

Sorts the lines read from the file, into a new collection, which you then proceed to print out.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"database.txt");
```

This is where you get your source for the scoreboard, the problem is its reading from the same file, and you never wrote back the sorted lines.

If you need to write the sorted list back to the file, you'd need to do something like:

```
var fileText = String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, orderedScores);
File.WriteAllText(filepath, orderedScores);
```

But, you don't have to write it back to the file. If all you want to do is display the sorted list, and not write it back to the file, all you have to do is loop through orderedScores; like this:

```
private void Leaderboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] scores = File.ReadAllLines(filepath); //filepath is equal to @database.txt file
        var orderedScores = scores.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1]));
        foreach (var entry in orderedScores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
            if (entry != null)
            {
                scoreboard.Items.Add(entry);
            }
        }
    }
```

And technically, since ListBox supports AddRange, all you have to do is:

```
private void Leaderboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        string[] scores = File.ReadAllLines(filepath); 
        scoreboard.Items.AddRange(scores.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1])));
    }
```

And as mentioned by @PaulF below you are writing out the unordered list each iteration through the ordered scores, you should be getting your list printed 3 times, unordered (which makes it appear as if your code is doing nothing, even though it is actually sorting the list)

You can fix this by replacing the `Console.WriteLine(scores)` with `Console.WriteLine(entry)`

Lastly, this still won't give you your desired result, as this will sort the file or the ListBox, but it'll be sorted ascending, you need to sort it descending:

```
private void Leaderboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        string[] scores = File.ReadAllLines(filepath); 
        scoreboard.Items.AddRange(scores.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1])));
    }
```

Comment: Note that you are writing out the unordered list each iteration through the ordered scores - you need _"Console.WriteLine(entry);"_

Comment: Aye, that's just a copy and paste from his code, I did notice that too, but I can add that to the answer, thanks Paul!

Comment: this worked!! thank you so much! I now understand it a lot more better too, thanks!!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OrderByDescending method.

```
private void Leaderboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] scores = File.ReadAllLines(filepath); //filepath is equal to @database.txt file
        var orderedScores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1]));
        foreach (var entry in orderedScores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"database.txt");
        while (line != null)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                scoreboard.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

Comment: See my answer, you are correct that it needs to be descending, but there's a bit more going on here, he's not actually sorting the file that he reads from twice.